# Leaflet Tag Filter Button and MarkerCluster.LayerSupport Plugins - Integration to make filters on click update the clusters

Tags: javascript, leaflet, filtering, leaflet.markercluster

I have 2 plugins that I want to work together: [Leaflet Tag Filter Button](https://github.com/maydemirx/leaflet-tag-filter-button) made by maydemirx and [MarkerCluster.LayerSupport](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport) made by ghybs (both awesome people and plugins btw). What I want to happen is when I click a filter on the tag filter button, I would like the marker clusters to update based on the new filter ([like this](https://www.kent.ac.uk/parrotnet/pnetfiles/pnetbigdata.html)). So a cluster of 5 points becomes 2, or a cluster of 10 becomes 1 marker. I succeeded in adding the layerSupported cluster to my map, so there's no hiccup there. I am unsure, though, how to integrate the supported cluster with the tag filter buttons, as they are two separate entities.

The Leaflet Tag Filter Button does support an [update() method and an enablePruneCluster method](https://github.com/maydemirx/leaflet-tag-filter-button#methods), both of which sound like they could be used to achieve what I'm looking for. Yet, when I apply them individually to the filter buttons, they don't work. I'm either applying the filter button methods incorrectly, creating the layerSupported cluster inaccurately, and/or the plugins were not made to be compatible with each other.

Here is my code for generating the layer supported marker cluster group:

```
var clusters = L.markerClusterGroup.layerSupport({maxClusterRadius:75}),
    group1 = L.layerGroup();
var getjson = $.getJSON("map-v2.geojson",function(data){
  var bev = L.geoJson(data,{
    pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
      var marker = L.marker(latlng, { tags: feature.properties.Genres.concat(feature.properties.Creator)});
      marker.bindPopup('<p align=center>' + '<strong>Title: </strong>' + feature.properties.Title + '<br/><a href="' + feature.properties.Image_Bank_URL + '" target="_blank"><img src="' + feature.properties.Thumbnail_URL + '"/></a><br/>' + '<strong>Date: </strong>' + feature.properties.Date + '<br/>' + '<strong>Creator: </strong>' + feature.properties.Creator, {minWidth : 250});
      return marker;
    }
  });
  bev.addTo(group1);
  clusters.addLayer(group1);
  map.addLayer(clusters);
});

// Here is where I add the layer supported clusters to the map.
clusters.checkIn(group1);
clusters.addTo(map);
```

Here is the section where I generate the tag filter buttons:

```
// Here is the code block for the Tag Filter Button. I start by accessing a tags file that has the data that I use for filter options. I should note that the genres.addToRelated is not working (it is supposed to link the 2 buttons together to work in conjunction with each other).
$.getJSON('tags.json', function(data) {
var genres = L.control.tagFilterButton({
  data: data.genres,
  filterOnEveryClick: true,
  icon: '<i class="fas fa-tags"></i>',
}).addTo(map);
var creators = L.control.tagFilterButton({
  data: data.creators,
  filterOnEveryClick: true,
  icon: '<i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>',
}).addTo(map);
jQuery('.easy-button-button').click(function() {
    target = jQuery('.easy-button-button').not(this);
    target.parent().find('.tag-filter-tags-container').css({
        'display' : 'none',
    });
});
genres.addToRelated(creators);
genres.update(clusters);
genres.enablePruneCluster(clusters);
});
```

If you'd like to see it all in action, here is a [plunker of the code](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Ee8QYy?preview).

Comment: Thx for the nice word! ;-)

Comment: Slightly cleaned up your code on Plunker and replaced the MCG by a normal Layer Group: for some reason the page hangs on Chrome and Firefox after opening the tag filter button and selecting one of the filters: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/r2PrtVJvlnQnJTA4

Comment: Tried on JSFiddle, same thing. So either my computer is strange, or there is something weird in your scripts / libraries.

Comment: It could be an issue with calling to update clusters - genres.update(clusters) - or since I deleted parts of my code to fit the plunker, it might be referencing something that no longer exists. I don't have any hang ups on my end, however. I noticed that your plunker did eliminate the marker clustering. I was hoping to avoid that, since I have some points that use the same latlong coordinates and I need the clusters to separate them on click. @ghybs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strangely the Leaflet Tag Filter Button plugin and/or latest Leaflet version look to have some bugs / listeners that may pause the script (hence the browser) when the Web Console is open.

Once those bugs are fixed, there are still bugs with the "`addToReleated`" method. Since I do not know what it is supposed to do, I will just ignore it for now, and let you possibly fix it with the plugin author.

As for integration with the [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugin, it really does not look like the 1st plugin is supposed to support it. [PruneCluster](https://github.com/SINTEF-9012/PruneCluster) plugin (for which the [`enablePruneCluster`](https://github.com/maydemirx/leaflet-tag-filter-button#methods) method of Tag Filter Button is intended) works very differently from Leaflet.markercluster.

By having a look into the source code of Tag Filter Button, it seems that you could implement it by adapting the [`enablePruneCluster`](https://github.com/maydemirx/leaflet-tag-filter-button/blob/0.0.4/src/leaflet-tag-filter-button.js#L77-L149) code and the `hide` function of the call to `registerCustomSource` in the default [`_prepareLayerSources`](https://github.com/maydemirx/leaflet-tag-filter-button/blob/0.0.4/src/leaflet-tag-filter-button.js#L174-L243). The idea is to avoid using directly the `_map`, and use an MCG instead.

Since you can directly handle calls to MCG `addLayers` and `removeLayers` within the `hide` function, there is really no need for the Leaflet.MarkerCluster.LayerSupport plugin at all.

Here is a quick and dirty implementation, called "`enableMCG`":

```js
////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Quick and dirty implementation of enableMCG
////////////////////////////////////////////////
L.Control.TagFilterButton.include({
  // Goal: read from MCG instead of from _map
  enableMCG: function(mcgInstance) {
    this.registerCustomSource({
      name: 'mcg',
      source: {
        mcg: mcgInstance,
        hide: function(layerSource) {
          var releatedLayers = [];

          for (
            var r = 0; r < this._releatedFilterButtons.length; r++
          ) {
            releatedLayers = releatedLayers.concat(
              this._releatedFilterButtons[r].getInvisibles()
            );
          }

          var toBeRemovedFromInvisibles = [],
            i,
            toAdd = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < this._invisibles.length; i++) {
            if (releatedLayers.indexOf(this._invisibles[i]) == -1) {
              for (
                var j = 0; j < this._invisibles[i].options.tags.length; j++
              ) {
                if (
                  this._selectedTags.length == 0 ||
                  this._selectedTags.indexOf(
                    this._invisibles[i].options.tags[j]
                  ) !== -1
                ) {
                  //this._map.addLayer(this._invisibles[i]);
                  toAdd.push(this._invisibles[i]);
                  toBeRemovedFromInvisibles.push(i);
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          }

          // Batch add into MCG
          layerSource.mcg.addLayers(toAdd);

          while (toBeRemovedFromInvisibles.length > 0) {
            this._invisibles.splice(
              toBeRemovedFromInvisibles.pop(),
              1
            );
          }

          var removedMarkers = [];
          var totalCount = 0;

          if (this._selectedTags.length > 0) {
            //this._map.eachLayer(
            layerSource.mcg.eachLayer(
              function(layer) {
                if (
                  layer &&
                  layer.options &&
                  layer.options.tags
                ) {
                  totalCount++;
                  if (releatedLayers.indexOf(layer) == -1) {
                    var found = false;
                    for (
                      var i = 0; i < layer.options.tags.length; i++
                    ) {
                      found =
                        this._selectedTags.indexOf(
                          layer.options.tags[i]
                        ) !== -1;
                      if (found) {
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                    if (!found) {
                      removedMarkers.push(layer);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }.bind(this)
            );

            for (i = 0; i < removedMarkers.length; i++) {
              //this._map.removeLayer(removedMarkers[i]);
              this._invisibles.push(removedMarkers[i]);
            }

            // Batch remove from MCG
            layerSource.mcg.removeLayers(removedMarkers);
          }

          return totalCount - removedMarkers.length;
        },
      },
    });

    this.layerSources.currentSource = this.layerSources.sources[
      'mcg'
    ];
  },
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Fix for TagFilterButton
////////////////////////////////////////////////
L.Control.TagFilterButton.include({
  _prepareLayerSources: function() {
    this.layerSources = new Object();
    this.layerSources['sources'] = new Object();

    this.registerCustomSource({
      name: 'default',
      source: {
        hide: function() {
          var releatedLayers = [];

          for (var r = 0; r < this._releatedFilterButtons.length; r++) {
            releatedLayers = releatedLayers.concat(
              this._releatedFilterButtons[r].getInvisibles()
            );
          }

          var toBeRemovedFromInvisibles = [],
            i;

          // "Fix": add var
          for (var i = 0; i < this._invisibles.length; i++) {
            if (releatedLayers.indexOf(this._invisibles[i]) == -1) {
              // "Fix": add var
              for (var j = 0; j < this._invisibles[i].options.tags.length; j++) {
                if (
                  this._selectedTags.length == 0 ||
                  this._selectedTags.indexOf(
                    this._invisibles[i].options.tags[j]
                  ) !== -1
                ) {
                  this._map.addLayer(this._invisibles[i]);
                  toBeRemovedFromInvisibles.push(i);
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          }

          while (toBeRemovedFromInvisibles.length > 0) {
            this._invisibles.splice(toBeRemovedFromInvisibles.pop(), 1);
          }

          var removedMarkers = [];
          var totalCount = 0;

          if (this._selectedTags.length > 0) {
            this._map.eachLayer(
              function(layer) {
                if (layer && layer.options && layer.options.tags) {
                  totalCount++;
                  if (releatedLayers.indexOf(layer) == -1) {
                    var found = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < layer.options.tags.length; i++) {
                      found =
                        this._selectedTags.indexOf(layer.options.tags[i]) !==
                        -1;
                      if (found) {
                        break;
                      }
                    }
                    if (!found) {
                      removedMarkers.push(layer);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }.bind(this)
            );

            for (i = 0; i < removedMarkers.length; i++) {
              this._map.removeLayer(removedMarkers[i]);
              this._invisibles.push(removedMarkers[i]);
            }
          }

          return totalCount - removedMarkers.length;
        },
      },
    });
    this.layerSources.currentSource = this.layerSources.sources['default'];
  },
});

////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Adapted from TagFilterButton demo
// https://github.com/maydemirx/leaflet-tag-filter-button/blob/0.0.4/docs/assets/js/main.js
////////////////////////////////////////////////
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  osmAttrib =
  '&copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
  osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, {
    maxZoom: 18,
    attribution: osmAttrib,
  });

// initialize the map on the "map" div with a given center and zoom
var releatedUsageMap = L.map('releated-usage-map')
  .setView([50.5, 30.5], 12)
  .addLayer(osm);

var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(releatedUsageMap);

L.marker([50.521, 30.52], {
    tags: ['tomato', 'active']
  })
  .bindPopup('tomato, active')
  .addTo(mcg);
L.marker([50.487, 30.54], {
    tags: ['tomato', 'ended']
  })
  .bindPopup('tomato, ended')
  .addTo(mcg);
L.marker([50.533, 30.5], {
    tags: ['tomato', 'ended']
  })
  .bindPopup('tomato, ended')
  .addTo(mcg);
L.marker([50.54, 30.48], {
    tags: ['strawberry', 'active']
  })
  .bindPopup('strawberry, active')
  .addTo(mcg);
L.marker([50.505, 30.46], {
    tags: ['strawberry', 'ended']
  })
  .bindPopup('strawberry, ended')
  .addTo(mcg);
L.marker([50.5, 30.43], {
    tags: ['cherry', 'active']
  })
  .bindPopup('cherry, active')
  .addTo(mcg);
L.marker([50.48, 30.5], {
    tags: ['cherry', 'ended']
  })
  .bindPopup('cherry, ended')
  .addTo(mcg);

var statusFilterButton = L.control
  .tagFilterButton({
    data: ['active', 'ended'],
    filterOnEveryClick: true,
    icon: '<span>suitcase</span>',
  })
  .addTo(releatedUsageMap);

// Enable MCG integration
statusFilterButton.enableMCG(mcg);

/*var foodFilterButton = L.control
  .tagFilterButton({
    data: ['tomato', 'cherry', 'strawberry'],
    filterOnEveryClick: true,
    icon: '<i class="fa fa-pagelines"></i>',
  })
  .addTo(releatedUsageMap);

foodFilterButton.addToReleated(statusFilterButton);*/
```

```css
html,
body,
#releated-usage-map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!-- Leaflet -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.3/leaflet.css" media="screen, print" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha512-Rksm5RenBEKSKFjgI3a41vrjkw4EVPlJ3+OiI65vTjIdo9brlAacEuKOiQ5OFh7cOI1bkDwLqdLw3Zg0cRJAAQ==" crossorigin="">
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.3/leaflet.js' integrity="sha512-tAGcCfR4Sc5ZP5ZoVz0quoZDYX5aCtEm/eu1KhSLj2c9eFrylXZknQYmxUssFaVJKvvc0dJQixhGjG2yXWiV9Q==" crossorigin=""></script>

<!-- MarkerCluster Plugin -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.3.0/MarkerCluster.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.3.0/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.markercluster/1.3.0/leaflet.markercluster.js'></script>

<!-- EasyButton Plugin (compatibility for tagFilterButton) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-easybutton@2/src/easy-button.js"></script>

<!-- tagFilterButton Plugin -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-tag-filter-button@0.0.4/src/leaflet-tag-filter-button.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet-tag-filter-button@0.0.4/src/leaflet-tag-filter-button.js"></script>

<div id="releated-usage-map"></div>
```

Comment: ghybs, you're a genius! I'm sorry it took so much trouble to make this work. If I'm understanding your fix correctly, we are replacing the default of the _map layer with our markerClusterGroup (mcg) layer for the tag filter button. That way, the filter button knows to filter the mcg layer, not the map level directly, which explains why individual points would filter, but not clusters. In order to do this, you made 2 functions for tag filter button: enableMCG that will accept mcg as the default layer, and a fix for registerCustomSource that includes a variable input (like mcg).

Comment: Exactly for the first part! As for the last "fix", it is only to get rid of some strange error messages thrown in Chrome due to undeclared `var`.